# DWT with more precise scale

Tags: discrete-signals, wavelet, python, time-frequency

With a signal `x` of length $2^{16}$,  the DWT (computed for example with pyWavelet's `wavedec`) has only 16 or 17 rows (the wavelet *scale* is dyadic).
Is there a DWT with more scales? (ex : 1024 rows instead of 16!)

Comment: Why do you need a more precise scale?

Comment: Because I want to use the scale axis of the wavelet transform (y-axis in a scalogram) as a frequency axis : with few scales (see http://www.mathworks.fr/help/releases/R2013b/wavelet/ref/cwt.gif) I get poor frequency resolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a continues wavelet transform (cwt) where you can specify the resolution of the scales (as done in the image you posted mathworks.fr/help/releases/R2013b/wavelet/ref/cwt.gif). The DWT only has $J$ scales by definition for $2^J$ signals.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is a confirmation of what I thought : I really need CWT.

Comment: The problem I have now with my $2^{16}$ length signal is : 1/ With DWT => too few scales (only 16!)   2/ With CWT, I can get as many scales that I want, BUT there will be too many time frames ! Example : I I do the CWT with 1024 scales ($s=s_0  2^{j/v}$) , the output array will be of shape $(1024, 2^{16})$

Comment: You could subsample the output, taking maybe every 32 columns.

Comment: Yes Gummi F, if I subsample (taking every 32 columns) I will have $(1024, 2048)$ instead of $(1024,2^{16})$, this is cool, but then will I be able to reconstruct the original signal with this subsampling ?
(probably yes, because even with this subsampling, I still have more $1024 * 2048$ coefficients, ie more than the original signal, and probably redudancy...) but how to reconstruct the original signal ?

Comment: I'm not sure, usually cwt is only used for analysis because it is redundant.